# compare value from datagridview to fileinfo

Tags: c#, datagridview, compare

in my program i have a datagridview,populated with 2 columns.
frist columns contains value like as filename.ext
second column contains size of this file.

now,i need to compare if file listed in column are present or not in a selected folder(selected by openfolder dialog)

i think have to use

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(fldChk.SelectedPath);
                FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.*");

                foreach (FileInfo file in rgFiles)
                  { //do there
```

i think use 2 array list,then add in frist filename,in second filesize.but is only supposition and for folder with many file,is very slow process.
what are best way to do thath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a FileInfo object to detect whether a file at a particular path exists.  Just use the [System.IO.File.Exists method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx).  If the path in the first column is a relative path, you'll have to prepend the absolute path to the path in the column before you call the Exists method.

```
var path = column.Text; // or wherever you get the path from
path = Path.Combine(@"C:\absolute\path\", path);
if (File.Exists(path))
{
   // Do something
}
```

Comment: path = Path.Combine(@"C:\absolute\path\", path); i use openfolderdialog for selecting path,how fix?

Comment: I assume you mean FolderBrowserDialog in which case you should make your code be: path = Path.Combine(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath, path);

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code based DataTable

```
var file = ...;
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(file);
FileSystemInfo f1 = new FileInfo(file);
dr = dt.NewRow();
//Get File name of each file name
dr["File_Name"] = f1.Name;
//Get File Size of each file in KB format
dr["File_Size"] = (f.Length / 1024).ToString();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

DataGridView.DataSource = dt;
DataGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: thank you for fast reply,can you explain this lines: DataGridView.DataSource = dt;
DataGridView.DataBind(); ?

Comment: you link your gridview with your datatable (source) and you bind in order to print datas, i'am happy to help you

Comment: I'am happy to help you devilkkw